# Unable to render the <input> HTML tag using react-native-render-html

Tags: html, input, warnings, render

**Input Tag not getting rendered**

Trying to render  tag using this package, but in return it gives a warning in the console which is:
The "input" tag is a valid HTML element, but is not handled by this library. You must extend the default HTMLElementModel for this tag with "customHTMLElementModels" prop and make sure its content model is not set to "none".  I have added the below code to remove the said warning

**TypeScript Code**

```
const source = {
  html: `
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <input type='text'>
  <h1>Bye</h1>
  `,
};

const customHtmlModel = {
 input: defaultHTMLElementModels.input.extend({
  mixedUAStyles: {
    width: 150,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  contentModel: HTMLContentModel.none,
 }),
};
```

**Render Tag**

````
<RenderHTML
        contentWidth={width}
        source={source}
        customHTMLElementModels={customHtmlModel}
/>```



All I can see is a plain yellow box, but it is not clickable and does not act like an input tag. 

How can I render an input field using this library? What steps needs to be taken.
````

Answer (score 0):

Every thing  is perfect just change the following:

```
const customHtmlModel = {
  input: defaultHTMLElementModels.input.extend({
    mixedUAStyles: {
      width: 150,
      height: 40,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    },
    contentModel: HTMLContentModel.void, // change this from none to void
  }),
};
```

Comment: Hello, i changed the HTMLContentModel from none to void, it made the warning pop up again in my emulator. And the yellow box is also not being rendered anymore.